# Self-signed certificate for applications on localhost - Socket TCP (TLS)

Tags: c#, sockets, go, certificate, tls1.2

I have a question regarding self-signed certificates.

I am developing a server with 2 different applications (one developed in go and the other in c #), each one has its own functionality but both connect with each other with a byte communication through TCP sockets with TLS.
My question is the following. Being a communication on localhost, can I use a self-signed certificate to encrypt the communication (TLS) or can it cause a vulnerability?

I have read that it is not recommended to use a self-signed certificate but I think that since it is a communication within the local machine itself, there may not be any problem in using it.

Comment: Self-signed certificates are fine if you have an out of band method of sharing the public keys. What is your goal with using TLS on localhost if it's not for authentication purposes?

Comment: Do you have any specific vulnerability in mind? With such small amount of details it is hard to provide concrete answers. As @JimB pointed out as long as both sides agree that it is valid cert there is no problem with TLS itself...

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you very much for answering. I do not have any specific vulnerability in mind, I only want to encrypt the communication locally to prevent any possible malware that can enter the server from capturing or altering the information. The project is specifically a dedicated server of a game and the 2 applications that connect are the main server (go) and the physics server (c#)

Comment: If the malware can intercept traffic on the loopback connection, it already has compromised your system. How would you pre-share the keys without having them exposed on the same host?

Comment: @JimB Ummm, I had not thought of something so obvious, it will not be very efficient to encrypt the communication if the certificates and even the public key is on the host itself ... What can be done in these cases? Assume that no malware entered the system? hahaha

Comment: If there is no malicious actor involved, what is the goal of the encryption? You can generate the keys on the fly and share them through some side channel, but is that going to protect you from whatever it is you are concerned about? You need to accurately describe the threat model before you can devise a plan to protect against it.